# Use 'window.open' and communicate with a child window

Tags: javascript, html, web, window.open

There are two pages in my tomcat server.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="onBtnClick()">jump to child</button>
<script>
    const msg = {
        name:'index.html',
        ifor:'I am your parent!'
    };
    function onBtnClick() {
        const childWindow = window.open('./child.html');
        childWindow.msg = msg
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msg-panel"></div>
<script>
    const msgPanel = document.querySelector('#msg-panel');
    msgPanel.innerHTML = `<span>${msg.name}</span><br><span>${msg.ifor}</span>`
    console.log(window.msg);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass some message( the msg Object in index.html) from **index.html** to **child.html**, by the way above.

When I click the button in **index.html** to open the **child.html**, sometimes I can get the msg object in **child.html**, but sometimes I can't.

Comment: You can put it into localStorage. Also, what's the end goal?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to write a publish page without backend ,  and the publish page  need some config from the index.html , so I want to pass msg from a html to another

Comment: And another question is how can I  know  the child.html is loaded in index.html.

Comment: The Window object returned by `open()` has an `onload` property, wait for it to fire before doing anything with your popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- make the button type="button"
- you set the message after opening. Sometimes the computer will be faster and not pass the message before it is shown. Use a timeout to show the message in the child OR
- - store the message in sessionStorage before calling window.open OR
- - have the child read the message from the parent:

---

```
const msgPanel = document.querySelector('#msg-panel');
msgPanel.innerHTML = `<span>${opener.msg.name}</span><br><span>${opener.msg.ifor}</span>`
  console.log(window.msg);
```

Comment: How can an asynchronous action (window.open) faster than a   synchronous action ( childWindow.msg = msg )?

Comment: Depends on the speed of the computer. It is obviously a timing issue. The message would normally not be available to the child, but while the child is rendering the now open window, it receives the msg sometimes in time to show it

Comment: Thanks a lot , your answer is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Because you sometimes get that message and sometimes not try to put code from script from index.html in this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
       //your code...
}
```

I think your html is not loaded and you click the button too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is already solved. Another alternative for sending data to a child would be `localstorage`. Getting and setting is really easy and IE11 is also supported.

```
localStorage.setItem('msg', 'something important');
let msg = localStorage.getItem('msg');
```

With that you would also have the ability to send data back and forth by setting event listeners on the localstorage change event like

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
    //do some cool stuff here
}
```

Just in case you want to have a more complex exchange between parent and child.

Comment: Your answer is very good too. I wiil try it! Thanks very much.